# Python - iterating over result of list.append

Tags: python, list

why can't I do something like this:

```
files = [file for file in ['default.txt'].append(sys.argv[1:]) if os.path.exists(file)]
```

Comment: I presume you've `import`ed `os`? But note: this is a list comprehension... not a generator expression.

Comment: What makes you think `append()` returns a value?  Where did you read there?  Where did you see any example like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`list.append` doesn't return anything in Python:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> k = l.append(5)
>>> k
>>> k is None
True
```

You may want this instead:

```
>>> k = [1, 2, 3] + [5]
>>> k
[1, 2, 3, 5]
>>>
```

Or, in your code:

```
files = [file for file in ['default.txt'] + sys.argv[1:] if os.path.exists(file)]
```

Comment: It is a fact to which I totally forgot

Comment: @Martin: no worries, we all forget things. Which is why it's always best to write short code samples in the interactive prompt before writing long comprehensions

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.chain#itertools.chain) if you don't want to duplicate lists.

```
files = [file for file in itertools.chain(['default.txt'], sys.argv[1:])
                  if os.path.exists(file)]
```